# What does invalid memory reference mean?

Tags: c

This is code I wrote for determining which string is lexographically (ASCII) greater, like 'Fun' is greater than 'Fan':

```
#include <stddef.h>

int StringCompare(const char* string1, const char* string2)
{
    while (*string1 && *string2 && *string1 == *string2) {
        string1++;
        string2++;
    }

    if (*string1 == *string2) {
        return 0; /*Strings are equal*/
    } else if (*string1 > *string2) {
        return 1; /*string1 is greater*/
    } else {
        return -1; /*string2 is greater*/
    }
}
```

When I run it, this is what I get:

```
Running test: StringCompare("qsuxt7lpo9?:x0kYHkLIy6nvCFE923z", "\_]YXe46Bqy5Wbp50I:2HupC=oAGqxz")  --  Passed
Running test: StringCompare("\_]YXe46Bqy5Wbp50I:2HupC=oAGqxz", "\_]YXe46Bqy5Wbp50I:2HupC=oAGqxz")  --  Passed
Running test: StringCompare("(null)", "Hello !!!???")  --  Failed: Invalid memory reference
```

What does it mean and how do I fix it?

**EDIT**: I fixed it!

```
    assert(string1 !=NULL);
    assert(string2 != NULL);
    
    while (*string1 && *string2 && (*string1 == *string2)) {
        string1++;
        string2++;
    }

    if (*string1 == *string2) {
        return 0; /*Strings are equal*/
    } else if (*string1 > *string2) {
        return 1; /*string1 is greater*/
    } else {
        return -1; /*string2 is greater*/
    }
```

Turns out that assert() can do a better job than a manual check

Comment: `NULL` is not a valid string. You cannot use `NULL` when a character array with one `'\0'` element (a *string*) is expected.

Comment: Is your test bed passing your comparator a null pointer and expecting you to handle that in some way? In real code, having null pointers in your array of strings is a failure on the data side, the comparator shouldn't be responsible for checking for/handling that (how do you even compare "not a string" to "a string"?).

Comment: Is there a reason you only compare the first character of each string?  Do you really intend `Fun` to compare equal to `Fan`?

Comment: `assert()` ***cannot*** do better than a (correct) manual check, and it is the wrong tool for the job of validating user input to boot.  `assert()` is for documenting and verifying program invariants, so if an assertion ever fails it means your program is incorrect.  And depending on how the program is compiled, assertions might have no effect at all.

Comment: Also, when an assertion fails that aborts the program.  Perhaps that's the expected result in your case (you haven't said), but that would be unusual.

Comment: `assert()` will not work if you compile in release mode (more precisely, when `NDEBUG` is defined) and your test harness will report failure again.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the calling code passed in a NULL pointer for the `string1` argument, and then you tried to dereference that NULL pointer (`*string1`) in the first line of your function, and that caused the program to fail.

You can fix it by testing your pointer-arguments and making sure not to dereference them if they are NULL, e.g.:

```
// check arguments and return early if they are invalid
if ((string1 == NULL)||(string2 == NULL)) return 0;
```

or, alternatively, if you wanted your function to treat a NULL pointer as equivalent to an empty string, you might do this:

```
if (string1 == NULL) string1 = "";
if (string2 == NULL) string2 = "";
```

Comment: Alternatively, if there's a requirement for a null pointer to compare equal to another null pointer, `if (!string1) { return !string2; }`.

Comment: Not that the actual `strcmp` has UB if either argument is a null pointer.

Comment: Or more specifically if either is not a null terminated string.

Comment: It's still not working - it just now says that ```StringCompare("(null)", "Hello !!!???")  --  Failed```. 
It's not the space because that has an ASCII value

Comment: What is the function expected to do when a NULL value is passed to it?  You can’t make it work correctly if you don’t know what the correct behavior is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

> Turns out that assert() can do a better job than a manual check.

`assert()` is a debugging tool for the programmer. If the code is compiled with `-DNDEBUG`, it is disabled and turns into a no-op, and your error-handling goes out of the window.

If the expected result is to `abort()` the program if a `NULL` pointer is passed in, you can change the code like so:

```
if (!string1 || !string2) {
    abort();
}
```

Or if the expected result is for the function to return `NULL`, replace the call to `abort()` with `return NULL`.

Alternatively, if there's a requirement for a `NULL` pointer to compare equal to another `NULL` pointer, consider:

```
if (!string1) { 
    return !string2; 
}

if (!string2) {
    return !string1;
}
```

@- Toby Speight

---

**Aside:**

```
 if (*string1 == *string2) {
        return 0; /*Strings are equal*/
    } else if (*string1 > *string2) {
        return 1; /*string1 is greater*/
    } else {
        return -1; /*string2 is greater*/
    }
```

can be simplified to:

```
return (*string1 > *string2) - (*string1 < *string2);
```

Comment: The code for `if (!string1)` needs to be supplemented by a test that `string2` is not null too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Code amended.

Comment: When you test `string2`, you know that `string1` is not null so you could simply return 0.  :D. (Just the trivia-minded fusspot!)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's better. (I appreciate the trivia-minded fusspot)